# Play Xml parser doesn't handle BOM (Byte Ordering Mark)

Tags: xml, playframework

I've written a simple xml endpoint using Play Framework 2.8.0 :

```
def xmlEndpoint: Action[NodeSeq] = Action.async(parse.xml) ...
```

to use it with a legacy client that sends a POST request with an `text/xml` content-type. The catch here is that the request body starts with a so called BOM (Byte Ordering Mark):

[image]

It's a this sequence `\357 \273 \277` that indicates UTF-8 is following in the body. Play detects this prefix and return an error:

```
For request 'POST /xmla' [Invalid XML: Content is not allowed in prolog.]
```

I tried getting the request without parsing it, then remove the prefixes like so:

```
def xmla: Action[AnyContent] = Action({ implicit r: Request[AnyContent] => {
  val validXmlBOM: Option[NodeSeq] = r.body.asText
    .map(_.replace("ï»¿", ""))
    .map(scala.xml.XML.loadString)
  Ok(validXmlBOM.get.toString())
}})
```

But didn't work for me. Play still detects that the body is a xml payload and try to parse it.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem ?
Maybe a custom made parser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just finished a custom parser that removes the BOM from request and parses it as a `NodeSeq` object. It's just a mockup, but it gives you the idea:

```
  def tolerantXmlBOM(maxLength: Long = 10000)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext): BodyParser[NodeSeq] =
BodyParser({ request: RequestHeader => {
  val sink: Sink[ByteString, Future[Either[Result, NodeSeq]]] = Flow[ByteString]
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), 1000, allowTruncation = true))
    .map(_.utf8String)
    .filterNot(_.startsWith("ï»¿"))
    .fold("") { case (acc, s) => acc + s }
    .map(s => {
      // todo should catch parsing error and return an error Result
      val parsed = scala.xml.XML.loadString(s)
      if (true) {
        Right(parsed)
      } else {
        Left(BadRequest("efefef"))
      }
    })
    .toMat(Sink.last)(Keep.right)
  Accumulator.apply(sink)
}
})
```

Also, I need to replace that conversion `utf8String` and work directly at byte level, since I have the input as `ByteString`.